# Correct format for slope and aspect in order to work in QGIS with "r.sun.insoltime"

Tags: qgis-3, slope, aspect

I'm using QGIS 3.10 and I should create a raster that shows the hours of sunlight referring to a given day for my province. `r.sun.insoltime` (Fig. 1, sorry it's in Italian but I traslate) to work asks me to insert a terrain model (DTM), an aspect map ("esposizione" in Italian) and a slope map ("pendenza" in Italian). I already have the DTM, while I have to make the other two maps. The question is: which is the unit of measure accepted by the algorithm "r.sun.insoltime" for slope and aspect maps?
Since under where the aspect layer is inserted there is written "a unique value of the orientation (aspect), 270 is south" I have to guess that the aspect must be in trigonometric angle (and then click on the box "return a trigonometric angle instead of the azimuth", Fig. 2), right? And the slope map (Fig. 3) instead must be calculated as a percentage or in degrees to work with `r.sun.insoltime`?

[image: Fig. 1strong text]

[image: Fig. 2]

[image: Fig. 3strong text]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Questions with bulleted lists of questions are closure bait.